# Why is this printing out the numbers from highest to lowest?

Tags: c#, stack

I'm currently taking a intermediate course on Udemy for C# and I'm trying to do one of the exercises. I've looked in the Q&A for students to see other peoples solutions, I've even copied and pasted other peoples solutions to see if theirs works and they do, I don't see any difference between mine and other peoples but for some reason my code prints out the numbers from highest to lowest and no where in the code should this happen. The idea of the exercise was to create a stack, we have 3 methods: Push(), Pop(), and Clear(). The push method adds objects to an ArrayList, the pop method removes the number from the top of the stack and returns the number. The clear method is self explanatory. Here's my code:

```
Stack Class:
public class Stack {
        private ArrayList _arrayList = new ArrayList();
        public void Push(object obj) {
            if (obj is null) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            else {
                _arrayList.Add(obj);
            }
        }

        public object Pop() {
            if (_arrayList is null) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            else {
                var top = _arrayList.Count;
                _arrayList.Remove(top);

                return top;
            }
        }

        public void Clear() {
            for (int i = 0; i < _arrayList.Count; i++) {
                _arrayList.Remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Program Class:

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var stack = new Stack();

            stack.Push(5);
            stack.Push(1);
            stack.Push(2);
            stack.Push(4);
            stack.Push(3);

            Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
            Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
            Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
            Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
            Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());

        }
    }
```

Comment: I certainly hope your course is not suggesting that you use `ArrayList`

Comment: Also you should be using the `==` operator, not the `is` keyword for your `if` conditions (does that even compile when comparing to `null`?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var top = _arrayList.Count;
_arrayList.Remove(top);

return top;
```

You aren't printing the values, you're printing the number of elements stored.

Try changing your values to be something other than the first few positive integers to catch this kind of mistake more easily.

PS: There's been no reason to use `ArrayList` for over a decade.  The generic collection classes such as `List<int>` are better in every way -- faster, less wasted memory, type safety.

Comment: note also that this is removing the number indicated by the count, regardless of index, so if Count is 5, and 5 is right in the middle of the array, then the middle item gets removed, not the first or last.

Answer (score 2):

```
var top = _arrayList.Count;
_arrayList.Remove(top);

return top;
```

`top` is assigned the value of the size of the list, and *is never reassigned*. Thus it looks like it prints highest to lowest because its just printing the size of the stack (which of course is 5, then 4, then 3, and so on). It only *looks* like you printed the contents of your list because you happened to push the same numbers. Some different test data would have made this bug more obvious.

I think what you *actually* wanted was

```
var top = _arrayList[_arrayList.Count -1];
```

Note that your code would fail miserably if there was a duplicate element in the list (due to removing based on the item value and not on the index). You also **really** shouldn't be using `ArrayList` at all; that's a .NET 1.0 class that's just an awful collection interface. Use a generic like `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning

```
 var top = _arrayList.Count;
```

Not the value in that position.

```
 _arrayList(top-1);
```

You should be getting an index out of range error on that remove.

```
_arrayList.Remove(top);
```